# gulp.parallel is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp

gulpfile.jsに関する質問です。
gulp、js初心者です。

## エラー

```
gulp.parallel is not a function
```

## 試みたこと

以下のサイトに従ってパッケージのgulpをアップデートするが、package.jsonではgulp 4.01
コマンドプロンプトでgulp -vをするとなぜか

```
CLI version 2.1.0
Local version 3.9.1
```

となってしまう

[古くなったgulpのプラグインをチェック&更新する方法 | NO:1572 | Webデザインリリック](https://kenyo--c.com/css/1572/)

## 質問

バージョンアップしてもエラーが消せませんでした。
どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

## gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

//pug
const pug = require('gulp-pug');
const fs = require('fs');
const data = require('gulp-data');
const path = require('path');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const notify = require('gulp-notify');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

//css
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sassGlob = require('gulp-sass-glob');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const flexBugsFixes = require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'); //Sassにベンダープレフィックスをつける
const rename = require('gulp-rename'); //ファイルをリネーム

/**
 * 開発用のディレクトリを指定します。
 */
const src = {
  // 出力対象は`_`で始まっていない`.pug`ファイル。
  'html': ['src/**/*.pug', '!' + 'src/**/_*.pug'],
  // JSONファイルのディレクトリを変数化。
  'json': 'src/_data/',
  'css': 'src/**/*.css',
  'sass_style': ['src/**/*.scss', '!' + 'src/**/_*.scss'],
  //'styleguideWatch': 'src/**/*.scss',
  'js': 'src/**/*.js'
};

/**
 * 出力するディレクトリを指定します。
 */
const dest = {
  'root': 'dest/',
  'html': 'dest/'
};

/**
 * PugのコンパイルやCSSとjsの出力、browser-syncのリアルタイムプレビューを実行します。
 */
function watchFiles(done) {
  gulp.watch(src.html).on('change', gulp.series(html, browserReload));
  gulp.watch(src.scss).on('change', gulp.series(sass_style, browserReload));
  gulp.watch(src.css).on('change', gulp.series(css, browserReload));
  gulp.watch(src.js).on('change', gulp.series(js, browserReload));
}

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel(html, sass_style, css, js), gulp.series(browsersync, watchFiles)));
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "gulp-pug-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "GulpでPugを実行するためのテスト環境です。",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gulp",
    "pug"
  ],
  "author": "aaa",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.4",
    "gulp": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-data": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-pug": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass-glob": "^1.0.9",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: 編集時にコード部分のみ選択した状態で `{ }` をクリックすると見やすく整形されますので、次回から試してみて下さい。

Comment: 一回 `node_modules` を削除し、再度インストールしてみてください。

Comment: @ PicoSushi 様
インストールしなおして実行してみると以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
assert.js:350
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
```
assert.jsに対して何かしないといけないのでしょうか

Comment: @cubick 様
例えば質問内容のfunction watchFiles(done) {}の部分ならこの部分のソースを選択して選択中に書いてある{}をクリックしたら良いということでしょうか？

Comment: @wa_ さん >
`assert.js:350 throw err; ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified`というエラーは、`gulp -v`を実行したときに発生したエラーでしょうか？もし違うのであれば、`gulp -v`を実行したときの結果を教えていただけませんか？

Comment: @supa 様 実行は npx gulpで行いました。今、手元にデータが無いので月曜日にgulp -v の結果をコメント入れます。すみません。。。

Comment: @supa 様 gulp -v を行ったところ、CLI version 2.1.0
Local version 4.0.1 と出ました。昨日も書いた通り、実行は npx gulp で行いました。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: @supa 様 ググって調べたところグローバルのバージョンを優先的に見てしまっているという記事を見ました。なので、package.json に "scripts": {"gulp": "gulp"}, を書き足したら assert.js:350 throw err; ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified というエラーは消えました。 新たに違うエラーが出たので新規で質問を書き込みたいと思います。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問でしたエラーはnode_modulesをインストールし直して消えました。
npx gulpを実行したところ以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
assert.js:350 throw err; ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
```

ググって調べたところグローバルのバージョンを優先的に見てしまっているという記事を見ました。
なので、
package.json

```
"scripts": {"gulp": "gulp"},
```

を書き足したら

```
assert.js:350 throw err; ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
```

というエラーは消えました。

参考:
[より便利になった gulp 4.0 への移行方法と変更点をまとめました - 株式会社クイックのWebサービス開発blog](https://aimstogeek.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/11/30/192238)